# Replace special character with their number of occurrence

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell variable

```
str= this 'is shell' script 'to learn'
```

I want to replace first occurrence of `'` with `" '` and second occurrence of `'` with `' "` and so on

finally

```
str= this "'is shell'" script "'to learn'"
```

Comment: How have you tried to solve this problem? What specific difficulties have you come across?

Comment: Do you want spaces between the quotes (as shown in "I want ..") or without (as shown in "finally") ?

Comment: As shown in the final string. I mentioned space to distinguished between single quotation and double quotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo $str | perl -pe "s|'(.*?)'|\"'\1'\"|g"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$ str=" this 'is shell' script 'to learn' "
$ echo $str
this 'is shell' script 'to learn'
$ perl -pe 's/\x27/sprintf("%s",++$i%2==0? "\"\x27" : "\x27\"")/ge' <<< "$str"
 this '"is shell"' script '"to learn"'
$
```